# Xlsxwriter doesn't do anything but no error message

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

```
import xlsxwriter

Workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook("Hello")
```

This is the code that doesn't work. I tried it with `Sheet`, I tried it with `write`. Then I boiled it down to the simplest form to find out where the problem is.

This should create an Excel file. But it doesn't.
The weird thing is, it doesn't even give me an error message. It just doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

after calling workbook.close only will save the excel file...you have missed this
This will create excel and write a value to cell 0,0

```
import xlsxwriter
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('Expenses01.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
row = 0; column = 0
worksheet.write(row, column, "Data to write")
workbook.close()
```

Mark as solved...

Comment: Thanks for your help.
But it still doesn´t work.
Copied and pasted the code.

Comment: the above code creates a new excel file with cell A1 = Data to write string

Comment: try copying full code and check file named Expenses will be available in the same folder